# Reference section with spaced words and unjustified items

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, line-breaking

I want to write a manuscript by `iopart` from IOP publishing group that can be found in this [page](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/). Unfortunately my references have problems. I attached tex and bib files.  many thanks in advance
[image]

```
%    INSTITUTE OF PHYSICS PUBLISHING                                   %
%                                                                      %
%   `Preparing an article for publication in an Institute of Physics   %
%    Publishing journal using LaTeX'                                   %
%                                                                      %
%    LaTeX source code `ioplau2e.tex' used to generate `author         %
%    guidelines', the documentation explaining and demonstrating use   %
%    of the Institute of Physics Publishing LaTeX preprint files       %
%    `iopart.cls, iopart12.clo and iopart10.clo'.                      %
%                                                                      %
%    `ioplau2e.tex' itself uses LaTeX with `iopart.cls'                %
%                                                                      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
% First we have a character check
%
% ! exclamation mark    " double quote  
% # hash                ` opening quote (grave)
% & ampersand           ' closing quote (acute)
% $ dollar              % percent       
% ( open parenthesis    ) close paren.  
% - hyphen              = equals sign
% | vertical bar        ~ tilde         
% @ at sign             _ underscore
% { open curly brace    } close curly   
% [ open square         ] close square bracket
% + plus sign           ; semi-colon    
% * asterisk            : colon
% < open angle bracket  > close angle   
% , comma               . full stop
% ? question mark       / forward slash 
% \ backslash           ^ circumflex
%
% ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 
% abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
% 1234567890
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\pdfminorversion=7
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
%\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}}
%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
%\usepackage{iopams}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax

\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cotinv}{cot\,inverse}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\amscases\cases
\makeatletter
\def\cases{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\plaincases\amscases}
\def\plaincases#1{\begin{cases*}#1\end{cases*}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\newcommand{\acot}{\cot^{-1}}
\begin{document}

\title[]{}

\author{sara}

\address{Department of }

\vspace{10pt}
\begin{indented}
\item[]November 2022
\end{indented}

\begin{abstract}
ll
\end{abstract}

%
% Uncomment for keywords
\vspace{2pc}
\noindent{\it Keywords}: physics
%
% Uncomment for Submitted to journal title message
%\submitto{\JPA}
%
% Uncomment if a separate title page is required
%\maketitle
% 
% For two-column output uncomment the next line and choose [10pt] rather than [12pt] in the \documentclass declaration
\ioptwocol
%



\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}
\par  Continuous-variable quantum key distribution (CV- QKD), dramatically developed over the past few years, is known as the strong counterpart for traditional discrete variable (DV) QKD  \cite{BB84} ...constructs a coherent state  and sends it to Bob. Bob decides to randomly measure one quadrature  \cite{GG02}  the excess noise of the reference signal due to the channel \cite{LLOnioseModel}, and $T$ is the channel transmittance: 
\newline\section{references}


\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{IOP}

\end{document}
```

and

```
    "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}"
    # "\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%"
} 
@proceedings{BB84,
    address = {India},
    author = {Bennett, C. H. and Brassard, G.},
    url = {https://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2ca89602a28a4416dfc6a74ffae7e3292/bronckobuster},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of IEEE International Conference on Computers, Systems, and Signal Processing},
    keywords = {},
    pages = {175},
    title = {Quantum cryptography: Public key distribution and coin tossing},
    year = {1984},
}
@article{GG02,
    title = {Continuous Variable Quantum Cryptography Using Coherent States},
    author = {Grosshans, Fr\'ed\'eric and Grangier, Philippe},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
    volume = {88},
    issue = {5},
    pages = {057902},
    numpages = {4},
    year = {2002},
    month = {Jan},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.057902},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.057902}
}

@misc{url,
    title = {LNP6118 - 40 GHz Phase Modulator,THORLABS},
    howpublished = {https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=LNP6118},
    note = {}
}
@article{LLOnioseModel,
    title = {Phase noise model for continuous-variable quantum key distribution using a local local oscillator},
    author = {Shao, Yun and Wang, Heng and Pi, Yaodi and Huang, Wei and Li, Yang and Liu, Jinlu and Yang, Jie and Zhang, Yichen and Xu, Bingjie},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. A},
    volume = {104},
    issue = {3},
    pages = {032608},
    numpages = {9},
    year = {2021},
    month = {Sep},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevA.104.032608},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.104.032608}
}
```

and the bbl file:

```
\providecommand{\newblock}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
  \def\url#1{{\tt #1}}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
\providecommand{\eprint}[2][]{\url{#2}}
% Bibliography created with iopart-num v2.1
% /biblio/bibtex/contrib/iopart-num

\bibitem{BB84}
 1984 {\em Quantum cryptography: Public key distribution and coin tossing\/}
  \urlprefix\url{https://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2ca89602a28a4416dfc6a74ffae7e3292/bronckobuster}

\bibitem{GG02}
Grosshans F and Grangier P 2002 {\em Phys. Rev. Lett.\/} {\bf 88}(5) 057902
  \urlprefix\url{https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.057902}

\bibitem{LLOnioseModel}
Shao Y, Wang H, Pi Y, Huang W, Li Y, Liu J, Yang J, Zhang Y and Xu B 2021 {\em
  Phys. Rev. A\/} {\bf 104}(3) 032608
  \urlprefix\url{https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.104.032608}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that latex does not find any good places to line break your very long urls. You can avoid the problem by adding the `xurl` package which adds more possible break points:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}

\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\ioptwocol
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{IOP}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter-is-at-topansw without your help I do not know how much time I need to resolve this problem. Your help is perfect and I am very lucky. Thank you very much

Comment: @sara00 You're welcome!